# Passing variable to paintComponent method

Tags: java, swing

I need some help. How does it pass a variable from class `Circle` to the `paintComponent` method because I want to make the circle change the x, y, w, h based on user input. Is there any idea to fix this? Since the problem there is an error after I press the button it doesn't execute anything.

Based on this image.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Circle extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
     private JPanel p1,p2,p3,buttonsize;
     private JLabel title,lb1,lb2,lb3,lb4,lb5,lb6,lb7,lb8,lb9,lb10;
     private JTextField circle1x,circle1y,circle1r,circle2x,circle2y,circle2r;
     private JButton drawButton;
     static int x1=30,x2=200,y1=10,y2=10,r1=10,r2=10;
    
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Circle c = new Circle();
        c.setSize(400,400);
        c.setTitle("Project");
        c.setVisible(true);
        c.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    
    public Circle()
    {
       
        title = new JLabel("Two circles intersect? No");
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(title);

        p2 = new JPanel();
        //p2.add(new Circles());
        
        lb1 = new JLabel("Enter circle 1");
        lb2 = new JLabel("Enter circle 2");
        lb3 = new JLabel("info:");
        lb4 = new JLabel("info:");
        lb5 = new JLabel("Center x:");
        lb6 = new JLabel("Center y:");
        lb7 = new JLabel("Radius:");
        lb8 = new JLabel("Center x:");
        lb9 = new JLabel("Center y:");
        lb10 = new JLabel("Radius:");
        
        circle1x = new JTextField(1);
        circle1y = new JTextField(1);
        circle1r = new JTextField(1);
        circle2x = new JTextField(1);
        circle2y = new JTextField(1);
        circle2r = new JTextField(1);
        drawButton = new JButton("Redraw Circles");
        buttonsize = new JPanel();
        buttonsize.setSize(50,50);
        buttonsize.add(drawButton);
        p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));

        p3.add(lb1);p3.add(lb3);p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(lb2);p3.add(lb4);
        p3.add(lb5);p3.add(circle1x);p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(lb8);p3.add(circle2x);
        p3.add(lb6);p3.add(circle1y);p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(lb9);p3.add(circle2y);
        p3.add(lb7);p3.add(circle1r);p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(lb10);p3.add(circle2r);
        p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(drawButton);p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(new JLabel(""));
        
        
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //call the constructor of the panel
        add(p1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new Circles(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p3,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        
        drawButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        double c1x = Double.parseDouble(circle1x.getText());
        double c1y = Double.parseDouble(circle1y.getText());
        double c1r = Double.parseDouble(circle1r.getText());
        double c2x = Double.parseDouble(circle2x.getText());
        double c2y = Double.parseDouble(circle2y.getText());
        double c2r = Double.parseDouble(circle2r.getText());
        
        x1 = (int) c1x;
        x2 = (int) c2x;
        y1 = (int) c1y;
        y2 = (int) c2y;
        r1 = (int) c1r;
        r2 = (int) c2r;
        
        
        if(e.getSource()== drawButton){
               repaint();
        }
            
        }

    }

class Circles extends JPanel
{
    

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(Circle.x1, Circle.y1, Circle.r1, Circle.r1);
        g.drawOval(Circle.x2, Circle.y2, Circle.r2, Circle.r2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the exception you get when you run the program. Also the user input values. It would be easier for anyone to help you out

Comment: What error do you get? If I try to compile your code, the compiler produces an error message "error: cannot find symbol" because you did not `import java.awt.BorderLayout;`. After fixing that problem your code compiles and seems to run as intended.

Comment: *"after I press the button it doesn't execute anything."* It does, here. It changes the [rendering on the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swvNZ.png) (though I think the code mixes up radius and diameter). Did you expect it to calculate whether or not the circles intersect and update the label at the top?  What code have you written to that end?

Comment: this is the error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Comment: Your JFrame class shouldn't be called Circle. Instead, you can have a real Circle class with properties of Circle only. Add another customised JPanel class. Add Circle into JPanel and JPanel into JFrame. Since they are contained within one another, you already have no problem accessing the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using static fields. Instead use setters in `Circles`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Circle extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private final JPanel p1,p2,p3,buttonsize;
    private final JLabel title,lb1,lb2,lb3,lb4,lb5,lb6,lb7,lb8,lb9,lb10;
    private final JTextField circle1x,circle1y,circle1r,circle2x,circle2y,circle2r;
    private final JButton drawButton;
    private final Circles circles;

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Circle c = new Circle();
        c.setSize(400,400);
        c.setTitle("Project");
        c.setVisible(true);
        c.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public Circle() {

        title = new JLabel("Two circles intersect? No");
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(title);

        p2 = new JPanel();

        lb1 = new JLabel("Enter circle 1");
        lb2 = new JLabel("Enter circle 2");
        lb3 = new JLabel("info:");
        lb4 = new JLabel("info:");
        lb5 = new JLabel("Center x:");
        lb6 = new JLabel("Center y:");
        lb7 = new JLabel("Radius:");
        lb8 = new JLabel("Center x:");
        lb9 = new JLabel("Center y:");
        lb10 = new JLabel("Radius:");

        circle1x = new JTextField(1);
        circle1y = new JTextField(1);
        circle1r = new JTextField(1);
        circle2x = new JTextField(1);
        circle2y = new JTextField(1);
        circle2r = new JTextField(1);
        drawButton = new JButton("Redraw Circles");
        buttonsize = new JPanel();
        buttonsize.setSize(50,50);
        buttonsize.add(drawButton);
        p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));

        p3.add(lb1);p3.add(lb3);p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(lb2);p3.add(lb4);
        p3.add(lb5);p3.add(circle1x);p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(lb8);p3.add(circle2x);
        p3.add(lb6);p3.add(circle1y);p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(lb9);p3.add(circle2y);
        p3.add(lb7);p3.add(circle1r);p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(lb10);p3.add(circle2r);
        p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(drawButton);p3.add(new JLabel(""));p3.add(new JLabel(""));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());  //BorderLayout is the default for JFrame
        //call the constructor of the panel
        add(p1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        circles = new Circles();
        add(circles,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p3,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        drawButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)   {

        if(e.getSource()!= drawButton)  return;
        
        double c1x = Double.parseDouble(circle1x.getText());
        double c1y = Double.parseDouble(circle1y.getText());
        double c1r = Double.parseDouble(circle1r.getText());
        double c2x = Double.parseDouble(circle2x.getText());
        double c2y = Double.parseDouble(circle2y.getText());
        double c2r = Double.parseDouble(circle2r.getText());

        circles.setX1((int) c1x);
        circles.setX2((int) c2x);
        circles.setY1((int) c1y);
        circles.setY2((int) c2y);
        circles.setR1((int) c1r);
        circles.setR2((int) c2r);
        repaint();
    }
}

class Circles extends JPanel{

    private int x1=30,x2=200,y1=10,y2=10,r1=10,r2=10;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(x1, y1, r1, r1);
        g.drawOval(x2, y2, r2, r2);
    }

    public void setX1(int x1) {
        this.x1 = x1;
    }

    public void setX2(int x2) {
        this.x2 = x2;
    }

    public void setY1(int y1) {
        this.y1 = y1;
    }

    public void setY2(int y2) {
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    public void setR1(int r1) {
        this.r1 = r1;
    }

    public void setR2(int r2) {
        this.r2 = r2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

This was a fun little project.  Because it is a project, I'm not going to provide all the code I wrote.  The reason I'm answering this question is to outline an approach to this Swing project or almost any Java project.

Here's the GUI I came up with.  It's a bit different than the OP's picture.

[image: Project GUI 1]

Here's another example.

[image: Project GUI 2]

And another.

[image: Project GUI 3]

## Explanation

When I create a Swing application, or most Java applications, I use the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern.  This pattern allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one part of the application at a time.

In a Swing GUI, the MVC pattern means:

1. The view reads information from the model.
2. The view does not modify the model in any way.
3. The controller updates the model and repaints / revalidates the view.

### Model

Rather than explaining a model, I'll just show you the model I created.

```
public class IntersectingCirclesModel {
    
    private Circle[] circles;
    
    public IntersectingCirclesModel() {
        this.circles = new Circle[2];
    }

    public boolean isIntersects() {
        double distanceX = Math.abs(circles[0].getCenter().getX() - 
                circles[1].getCenter().getX()); 
        double distanceY = Math.abs(circles[0].getCenter().getY() - 
                circles[1].getCenter().getY()); 
        double distance1 = (distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);
        
        double radius1 = circles[0].getRadius();
        double radius2 = circles[1].getRadius();
        double diameter = radius1 + radius2;
        double distance2 = diameter * diameter;
        
        System.out.println(distance1 + " " + distance2);
        return distance1 <= distance2;
    }

    public Circle[] getCircles() {
        return circles;
    }
    
    public void setCircle(Circle circle, int index) {
        this.circles[index] = circle;
    }
}

public class Circle {
    
    private int radius;
    
    private Point center;

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

    public void setCenter(Point center) {
        this.center = center;
    }
    
    public void setCenter(int x, int y) {
        this.center = new Point(x, y);
    }
    
}
```

I created two plain Java getter / setter classes.  The first class, the `Circle` class, holds a radius and a center point.  I used a `java.awt.Point` to hold the center point.

The second class, the `IntersectingCirclesModel` class, is the application model.  This class holds an array of two `Circle` instances and calculates whether or not the two `Circle` instances intersect.

The intersect calculation is pretty simple.  The distance between the two center points has to be less than the distance of the two radii added together.  I actually calculate the distance squared so I don't have to take square roots.

### View

The view consists of one `JFrame`, one drawing `JPanel`, two instances of one entry `JPanel`, and a `JPanel` to hold the two instances of one entry `JPanel` and the `JButton`.

I use these Swing components.  The only Swing component I extend is `JPanel` to create the drawing `JPanel`.  I do this so I can override the `paintComponent` method.  The first line in my `paintComponent` method is a call to the super `paintComponent` method to maintain the Swing paint chain.

I create the `JFrame` by creating the subordinate `JPanels`, packing the `JFrame`, and setting the `JFrame` visible.

The drawing `JPanel` is straightforward.  I extend a `JPanel`.  I pass an instance of the model class to the drawing `JPanel`.  In the constructor, I set the background color and set the preferred size of the `JPanel`.

The `paintComponent` method checks to see if the two `Circle` instances have been created.  If so, the circles are drawn and the intersect text at the top of the drawing `JPanel` is drawn.

The entry `JPanel` is a separate class.  I do this so I only have to create one entry panel.  The only difference between the two entry panels is the title, so I pass the title into the class through the constructor.

I create the entry `JPanel` using a [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).  The `GridBagLayout` is the layout to use when you want to create any `JPanel` that looks like a form.

I create a consolidating `JPanel` by creating two instances of the entry `JPanel`.  This consolidating `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout`.

I create an additional consolidating `JPanel` using a `BorderLayout`.  This `JPanel` puts the previous consolidating `JPanel` in the CENTER position and a `JButton` in the AFTER_LAST_LINE position.

You can create a complex GUI by nesting `JPanels` with simpler Swing layouts.

The `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`.  I put the drawing `JPanel` in the CENTER position and the additional consolidating `JPanel` in the AFTER_LAST_LINE position.

### Controller

The controller is the `ActionListener` triggered by the `JButton`.  I pass an instance of the GUI class and an instance of the model class to the controller class.  The `actionPerformed` method gets the values from the two entry `JPanels`, adds the center point and radius to the two circles, and has the GUI repaint the drawing `JPanel`.

## Edited to Add 1

The OP's comment leaves out a lot of information.  Here's the class I created to create one instance of the entry `JPanel`.  You have to create two instances of this class for the two entry `JPanels`.

```
public class CircleEntryPanel {
    
    private JPanel panel;
    
    private JTextField centerxField;
    private JTextField centeryField;
    private JTextField radiusField;
    
    public CircleEntryPanel(String title) {
        this.panel = createCircleEntryPanel(title);
    }

    private JPanel createCircleEntryPanel(String title) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        
        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(title);
        panel.add(titleLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel centerxLabel = new JLabel("Center x:");
        panel.add(centerxLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        centerxField = new JTextField(4);
        centerxField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
        panel.add(centerxField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel centeryLabel = new JLabel("Center y:");
        panel.add(centeryLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        centeryField = new JTextField(4);
        centeryField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
        panel.add(centeryField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel radiusLabel = new JLabel("Radius:");
        panel.add(radiusLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        radiusField = new JTextField(4);
        radiusField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
        panel.add(radiusField, gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

    public JTextField getCenterxField() {
        return centerxField;
    }

    public JTextField getCenteryField() {
        return centeryField;
    }

    public JTextField getRadiusField() {
        return radiusField;
    }

}
```

## Edited to Add 2

Enough time has passed for me to post the complete runnable code for this project.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I can post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class IntersectingCirclesGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new IntersectingCirclesGUI());
    }
    
    private IntersectingCirclesModel model;
    
    private CircleEntryPanel[] entryPanels;
    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    public IntersectingCirclesGUI() {
        this.model = new IntersectingCirclesModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Project");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        panel.add(createEntryPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Redraw Circles");
        button.addActionListener(new CircleListener(this, model));
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createEntryPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        entryPanels = new CircleEntryPanel[2];
        entryPanels[0] = new CircleEntryPanel("Enter Circle 1 info:");
        entryPanels[1] = new CircleEntryPanel("Enter Circle 2 info:");
        
        panel.add(entryPanels[0].getPanel());
        panel.add(entryPanels[1].getPanel());
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }
    
    public CircleEntryPanel[] getEntryPanels() {
        return entryPanels;
    }

    public class CircleEntryPanel {
        
        private JPanel panel;
        
        private JTextField centerxField;
        private JTextField centeryField;
        private JTextField radiusField;
        
        public CircleEntryPanel(String title) {
            this.panel = createCircleEntryPanel(title);
        }
    
        private JPanel createCircleEntryPanel(String title) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
            
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            
            JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(title);
            panel.add(titleLabel, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridy++;
            JLabel centerxLabel = new JLabel("Center x:");
            panel.add(centerxLabel, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx++;
            centerxField = new JTextField(4);
            centerxField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
            panel.add(centerxField, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            JLabel centeryLabel = new JLabel("Center y:");
            panel.add(centeryLabel, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx++;
            centeryField = new JTextField(4);
            centeryField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
            panel.add(centeryField, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            JLabel radiusLabel = new JLabel("Radius:");
            panel.add(radiusLabel, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx++;
            radiusField = new JTextField(4);
            radiusField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
            panel.add(radiusField, gbc);
            
            return panel;
        }

        public JPanel getPanel() {
            return panel;
        }

        public JTextField getCenterxField() {
            return centerxField;
        }

        public JTextField getCenteryField() {
            return centeryField;
        }

        public JTextField getRadiusField() {
            return radiusField;
        }
    
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private IntersectingCirclesModel model;
        
        public DrawingPanel(IntersectingCirclesModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3f));
            
            boolean circlesDrawn = false;
            Circle[] circles = model.getCircles();
            for (int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                if (circles[i] != null) {
                    paintCircle(g2d, circles[i]);
                    circlesDrawn = true;
                }
            }
            
            if (circlesDrawn) {
                String text = (model.isIntersects()) ? "Yes" : "No";
                text = "Two Circles Intersect? " + text;
                Font font = getFont();
                FontRenderContext frc =
                        new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

                Rectangle2D r2D = font.getStringBounds(text, frc);
                int rWidth = (int) Math.round(getWidth());
                int textWidth = (int) Math.round(r2D.getWidth());
                int textHeight = (int) Math.round(r2D.getHeight());

                int a = (rWidth - textWidth) / 2;
                int b = textHeight + 5;

                g2d.drawString(text, a, b);
            }
        }

        private void paintCircle(Graphics2D g2d, Circle circle) {
            int radius = circle.getRadius();
            int diameter = radius + radius;
            Point point = circle.getCenter();
            g2d.drawOval(point.x - radius, point.y - radius, 
                    diameter, diameter);
        }
    }
    
    public class CircleListener implements ActionListener {
        
        private IntersectingCirclesGUI frame;
        
        private IntersectingCirclesModel model;

        public CircleListener(IntersectingCirclesGUI frame, 
                IntersectingCirclesModel model) {
            this.frame = frame;
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            CircleEntryPanel[] entryPanels = frame.getEntryPanels();
            Circle[] circles = model.getCircles();
            for (int i = 0; i < entryPanels.length; i++) {
                circles[i] = createCircle(entryPanels[i]);
            }
            frame.repaint();
        }
        
        private Circle createCircle(CircleEntryPanel panel) {
            int x = valueOf(panel.getCenterxField().getText().trim());
            int y = valueOf(panel.getCenteryField().getText().trim());
            int radius = valueOf(panel.getRadiusField().getText().trim());
            
            Circle circle = new Circle();
            circle.setCenter(x, y);
            circle.setRadius(radius);
            
            return circle;
        }
        
        private int valueOf(String number) {
            try {
                return Integer.valueOf(number);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class IntersectingCirclesModel {
        
        private Circle[] circles;
        
        public IntersectingCirclesModel() {
            this.circles = new Circle[2];
        }

        public boolean isIntersects() {
            double distanceX = Math.abs(circles[0].getCenter().getX() - 
                    circles[1].getCenter().getX()); 
            double distanceY = Math.abs(circles[0].getCenter().getY() - 
                    circles[1].getCenter().getY()); 
            double distance1 = (distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);
            
            double radius1 = circles[0].getRadius();
            double radius2 = circles[1].getRadius();
            double diameter = radius1 + radius2;
            double distance2 = diameter * diameter;
            
            System.out.println(distance1 + " " + distance2);
            return distance1 <= distance2;
        }

        public Circle[] getCircles() {
            return circles;
        }
        
        public void setCircle(Circle circle, int index) {
            this.circles[index] = circle;
        }
    }
    
    public class Circle {
        
        private int radius;
        
        private Point center;

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public void setRadius(int radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public Point getCenter() {
            return center;
        }

        public void setCenter(Point center) {
            this.center = center;
        }
        
        public void setCenter(int x, int y) {
            this.center = new Point(x, y);
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea :D appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you.. just want to ask for the input text field part.. sorry so beginner here.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. I hope I can understand those codes that you gave because I'm a beginner at this java language. I will get back to you if I got any problems.